# Handling file name before saving in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I am building this app and I am looking to save different images on the disk, I generate random names for the files so I do not overwrite the previous one, my goal is to save that name file to a db so I can access it later on the front-end, the files get saved to the public directory so I can simply append the file name to the server url like so

> http://localhost:8080/123.png

The code below show how the function works:

```
var url =  'https://www.google.com';

app.get('/api', (request, response) => {
  webshot( url ,'public/' + Date.now() + '.jpg' , options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else {
      console.log('SS OK');
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url =  "https://www.google.com"

app.get('/api', (request, response) => {
     var filename = Date.now() + '.jpg'
     webshot( url ,'public/' + filename , options, 
        function (err) {
           if (err) {
              console.log(err)
           }
           else {
              console.log('SS OK')
              //save filename in DB
           }
        });
     })
```